# How can i reduce the execution time on this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization

I've never learnt to optimize my JOINS and at least one of these tables has over 200,000 rows, I was wondering if someone could recommend any improvements to decrease the executing time, suggestions on SQL as well as how to optimize the table, such as indexing. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
  t.entry_id as entry_id, 
  status, 
  entry_date, 
  child_entry_id as skill_id, 
  parent_id as cat_parent,
  field_id_4 as tunnel, 
  field_id_140 as log_instructor, 
  field_id_2 as log_time, 
  field_id_17 as log_video, 
  field_id_18 as log_comments, 
  field_id_86 as log_instructor_comment, 
  field_id_93 as logbook_denial_explanation, 
  field_id_119 as log_instructor_comment_add
FROM 
  exp_playa_relationships r, 
  exp_channel_titles t, 
  exp_channel_data d, 
  exp_category_posts p, 
  exp_categories c
WHERE 
  d.channel_id = 7
  AND d.entry_id = t.entry_id
  AND t.status != 'Delete'
  AND author_id = '1'
  AND t.entry_id = r.parent_entry_id
  AND r.parent_field_id = 19
  AND child_entry_id = p.entry_id
  AND p.cat_id = c.cat_id
  AND c.parent_id IN(37,38,39,40,41)
  ORDER BY entry_id DESC
```

Comment: You should learn to write JOINs.  Hint:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Makes the query much easier to read so other people can help you.

Comment: You should run `EXPLAIN` on your query and then look for places to improve.  Adding indices to the columns involved in the joins and `WHERE` clause might be a good place to start.

Comment: Start by reading [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Then rewrite your query using `JOIN`. After that, try `CREATE INDEX` for tables in columns appear in your `ON` clause. Learn using `EXPLAIN` and reading [execution plan](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/primary-keys) to optimize the way database execute your query.

Comment: When asking questions about SQL queries, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each table and include the output. Then run `EXPLAIN <query>` and include the output. That will help us so we don't have to guess at your columns and indexes.

Comment: Need more info.  Which tables are `author_id` and `child_entry_id` in?  Please use `JOIN..ON` syntax.  Let's see the indexes you already have.  Which `entry_id` do you want to sort by?